# record realtime data to mongodb using nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

How I can pick `JSON.stringify` and post to my mongoDB Database?

For Exemple:

```
import express from 'express';

let data_record = JSON.stringify({**any content**})
```

This code will automatically receive data every 60 seconds and I want post this data to my DB.

I set the route like below:

```
app.post('/recording/ttn', (req, res) => {
  res.send(data_record);
});
```

Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: what exactly is your problem, what does not work and how should it work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want to get to, but to do something after a known interval (in this case store to DB), use setInterval(60 * 1000) which comes in javascript by default, or use the Math Mod operation. e.g:

```
if (seconds_counter % 60 === 0) {
    //Post to DB
    //seconds_counter, would need to increment every second by 1
}
```

Comment: Is that, but i don't know how can i "//post to DB". I know how do this with my user send data from browser in a form, but not from my file .js

Comment: Its a very broad question, and i guess you need to watch some tutorials. Plus we don't know want you want to add. Btw accept the answer if has given some idea about your question. Thanks